# How to send SendKeys to Windows form in python script?

Tags: winforms, python-2.7, ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm doing automation scripting in Python for my desktop application. 
In that I'm sending TAB key/any key to my windows form. But I'm not able to find handle of that Windows form in my Python script.

Here is the sample code snippet :

```
__author__ = 'juhis'

import SendKeys
import sys
import os
from Tkinter import *
import ctypes
import win32gui
import pywinauto

pwapp = pywinauto.application.Application()
whandle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re='Form1',class_name='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2bf8098_r13_ad1')[0]
window1 = pwapp.window_(handle=whandle)
window1.SetFocus()

SendKeys.SendKeys("""{PAUSE 2}""")
SendKeys.SendKeys("""{TAB 2}{PAUSE 2}{ENTER}""")
```

Please help me to figure out the issue.

-Thanks

Comment: What is the output of the script?

Comment: i'm just getting following output on console : 
with exit code 1

But those TAB buttons not getting clicked on that Win Form

Comment: It looks like you use old version of SWAPY for code generation. Please use [the latest SWAPY](https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY/releases) and pywinauto 0.5.4. If the problem persists, just update the question and let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code can be re-written simpler:

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(title_re='Form1')
Form1 = app.Window_(title_re='Form1', class_name='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2bf8098_r13_ad1')
Form1.SetFocus()
Form1.TypeKeys("{PAUSE 2}")
Form1.TypeKeys("{TAB 2}{PAUSE 2}{ENTER}")
```

`TypeKeys` automatically sets a focus to the `Form1` and types the keys. `SendKeys` doesn't set a focus because it's not aware about the window. That's probably why it doesn't work with `SendKeys`.

[EDIT] Of course you need to run the script as Administrator.

Comment: Vasily,
I tried your code. But still its not working. Its set the focus on that form, it means its getting a proper handle of that form. But its not sending any keys to that form. 
And I'm getting output message on console "return with exit code 0"

Comment: Are you running your Python script as Administrator?

Comment: The comment is very useful. Running as Admin fixed my problem as well. Vasily, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got a fixed for this issue. The mistake I was doing is that, I was not running my script as Administrator. So that's why SendKeys event were not happening.

But when I ran my script as Administrator, SendKeys event successfully sent to Windows form.

Thanks Vasily for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Just for your info: marking correct answers as accepted is considered polite on StackExchange. It's a signal for other users that the problem is really solved. And if you don't do that, it can demotivate experts to answer your questions.

Comment: Sure Vasily. I'll keep this thing in mind. But for now, I dont have enough reputation points to mark correct answer.

Comment: You need 15 rep points to vote up, but accepting answers is available to every author of a question.

Comment: ohoo yeah !! got it. I was confused in that. thank you.